# Bean Validation message interpolation with array constraint parameter used as variable in message

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

#### Is it possible to join the int array arguments in javax.validation error message interpolation?

I want to validate a string for different possible lengths and
I started implementing a custom constraint:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {BarcodeValidator.class})
public @interface Barcode {
String message() default "{validation.Barcode.message}";
  int[] lengths();
}
```

The validator:

```
public class BarcodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Barcode, String> {

  private List<Integer> lengths;

  @Override
  public void initialize(Barcode barcode) {
    lengths = new ArrayList<>(barcode.lengths().length);
    for (int l : barcode.lengths()) lengths.add(l);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return value != null && lengths.contains(value.length());
  }
}
```

I would like a custom message for it like:
*The barcode must be 12/23/45 character long!*

I have figured out I can use the annotation parameters in the message, so I would like to do something like:

```
validation.Barcode.message = The barcode must be ${'/'.join(lengths)} character long!
```

Is something like that possible or should I do it in some other way?

(P.S.: My first question here on SO.)

Comment: Have you actually tried? Bean Validation allows to use EL expressions, however 'join' is really a static method of `String` in Java 8. So I would expect it to be `${String.join('/', lengths)}`, but I am not sure how EL is dealing with static methods. I would just try.

Comment: @Hardy Thanks for the tip.I tried it but it seems that the only [a formatter bean](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html) is enabled in the Expression language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution.
Validator class:

```
public class BarcodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Barcode, String> {

  private List<Integer> lengths;

  @Override
  public void initialize(Barcode barcode) {
    lengths = new ArrayList<>(barcode.lengths().length);
    for (int l : barcode.lengths()) lengths.add(l);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class).addExpressionVariable("joinedLengths", String.join(" / ", lengths));
    return value != null && lengths.contains(value.length());
  }
}
```

*.properties:

```
validation.Barcode.message = The barcode must be ${joinedLengths} character long!
```

Also tried naming the parameter `lengths`, but that did not work - it is probably bound to the type `int[]`.